# Links in nomination flag descriptions aren't colored unlike for Q&A's

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, flag-dialog, nominations

The links ("[does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)"
and "[inappropriate for respectful discourse](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)") aren't colored for the "spam" and "rude or abusive" flag descriptions in **nominations**:

- On English Language & Usage:

  [image]
- On Mythology & Folklore:

  [image]

Unlike for Q&A's where the links are colored:

- On English Language & Usage:

  [image]
- On Mythology & Folklore:

  [image]

Comment: This is still an issue (tested on [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election)). It looks like there are no links at all, just plain text until you hover over the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! This should be fixed now.